# Selecting a date in the future

Tags: sql

I am working on a shipment delivery report to determine if shipments are made within a shipment window.

Every release has a Ship_Date value that is the date that the release must ship.  Some releases though have a late window integer value that says if the shipment is made within X number of days then it is still considered on time.

This is complicated by another table which holds valid ship days for the month (used to exclude holidays, weekends, and such).

```
Order_Releases_Table
  Part_No,
  Quantity,
  Ship_Date,
  Window

Shipping_Date
  Shipping_Day
```

Sample Data

```
Order_Releases_Table
Part_No  Quantity  Ship_Date  Window
ABC      100       9/1/2011   0
XYZ      200       9/1/2011   2

Shipping_Date
9/1/2011
9/2/2011
9/5/2011
```

So with this data part ABC has to ship on 9/1 to be considered on time.  Part XYZ though can ship up to 2 days past 9/1 and still be considered on time, but since 9/3 isn't in our shipping days, then 9/5 is the last day it can ship and still be considered on time.

I think the answer lies in joining in a sub query of the shipping days table that assigns a row number to the shipping_day field.

```
SELECT
  Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Shipping_Date) AS Day_No,
  Shipping_day
FROM Shipping_Date
WHERE Shipping_Day > Ship_Date

RETURNS
Day_No  Shipping_Day
1       9/2/2011
2       9/5/2011
```

Then if I simply pick up the date where the Day_No from this sub query is equal to window value from the release, I then have the last day a particular shipment can ship and still be considered on time.

I'm having a hard time wrapping it all up in to the final query though.

Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: What do you want the final report to look like?

Comment: With the 2 example entries in the release table ABC, 100, 9/1/2011 and XYZ, 200, 9/5/2011.  Basically it needs to dynamically re-adjust for each release because every release can have an independent window.  I'll be using that date to bounce against my shipper table to figure out if the shipper was in fact shipped on time.

Comment: thats gonna be a little tricky to do in SQL.  Something like this I'd probably prefer to do in code because set-based logic (ie. SQL) doesn't seem like a good fit.

Comment: Unfortunately all I've access to is SQL. I've never used a cursor before, but could it possibly help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Part CHAR(3), ShipDate DATETIME, Window INT)
DECLARE @ship TABLE (ShipDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t
        ( Part, ShipDate, Window )
SELECT 'abc', '20110901', 0
UNION
SELECT 'xyz', '20110901', 2


INSERT INTO @ship
        ( ShipDate )
SELECT   '20110901'  
UNION
SELECT '20110905'
UNION
SELECT '20110910'


SELECT Part, ShipDate, Window,
    (SELECT MIN(ShipDate) AS NextShip
      FROM @ship S 
      WHERE s.shipDate >= DATEADD(day, t.Window, t.shipDate))
FROM @t t
```

Comment: Awesome.  This got me where I needed to e.